Composition of loops
I am currently trying to understand the proof in this short paper:
A Topological Puzzle, by I. Bertuccioni. One of the parts I don't get is contained in the following picture:

This depicts some wire in 3D (dark and gray lines), the dotted lines represents loops. The authors works on $\mathbb{S}^3$, the one point compactification of the space, so one can understand these loops to close "at infinity" so it is why they don't draw the loops as closed in the picture, but they are.
I would like to understand (prove of convince myself) that the loop dud^{-1}g is really what it claims to be. As I understand it, one should follows the loop $g$, then the inverse of $d$, then $u$ and finally $d$. I am struggling to "view" it.
Is there an easy way of seeing it? Any help, hint or answer will be greatly appreciated.
I am not very familiar with algebraic topology. So, I understand that this seems to be a very basic question, so treat me as a beginner in this field.

So I see some connections, but I'm not able to do it consistently. Are you saying that there is no "general" idea that could be use to see it?

What are you looking for, exactly? You could always build a 3D model in some software, or out of strings or something...

I'm looking for an algebraic proof. Or some compelling computation. Yes I can verify this by building a model in 3D with strings and wires. But then I won't be able to generlize in 4D. Never!

Well, all you have is a picture of a 3D object, not an algebraic description. If you want to be systematic about the manipulations you could think in terms of Reidemeister moves, but I think there's no escaping some spatial reasoning.

I hope this will make is easier to "view". You want to see that it is equivalent to the red loop here:

That is, $d$, then $u$, then $d^{-1}$ (which I moved to the side slightly), then $g$. Now, deform this as follows:




So we end up with a loop that goes though the ring and behind its "neck", as we wanted.

Excellent! Thank you very much for the effort you put in. I draw many things but I was never able to see it!
